# why does my iMac has two IP addresses registered?

Tags: airport, network

I have been doing network ping discovery on a WiFi-LAN and one of my iMac has two IP addresses, and I cannot understand why would that be.

the only connection to the LAN is via Wifi, there is no file sharing, no Ethernet, no Bluetooth or any other network services (apart from screen sharing).

Comment: What commands did you use to find this and what exactly did they show?

Comment: A terminal dump might assist.  It is possible to have virtual interfaces providing more than one IP on a single physical interface.  Try (sorry, not at a mac, might have these wrong) this on a terminal to see what interfaces you have up directly on the mac, rather than pinging it. `ifconfig -a` to list all active interfaces, both physical and virtual, and their properties.

Answer (score 2):

I have 4 IP addresses on some of my Mac's network interfaces since I set them up in network preferences control panel.

You could go there and delete all un-needed IP addresses or at least know it's not something that was intended.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on you LAN setup, this can happen if the computer has ethernet and wifi both turned on.

You can verify from the Mac in System Preferences->Network: if both Ethernet and Wifi are green that's it.

In this case the Mac will use the first one listed--- either make sure the faster connection is first or turn off the slower.